# Webservice variable to return response

Tags: php, web-services, httprequest

I am not a professional (so be indulgent) and I come with a question that must be very obvious but browsing the web doesn't provide me with a clear answer.

I have made a little web site with a MySQL database behind and I also have developed a little app in Flutter to feed the database. I have written a very simple web service in php based on the php "script" that I use in my webpage to send the result of a form to the database.

In flutter I will use a httpRequest to send the info to the web service (a Post method).
Hereunder you find the code of the project for my web service :

```
<?php
//Connexion à la DB
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=name', 'root', 'root');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

//Lecture du POST
$var1 = isset($_POST["var1"])? htmlspecialchars($_POST["var1"]): "";
$var2 = isset($_POST["var2"])? htmlspecialchars($_POST["var2"]): "";

//Insertion des données
$req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (var1, var2) values (?,?)");
$req->execute(array($var1, $var2,));

//Header
header('Content-type: application/json');
 ?>
```

I believe I don't have to do anything special to send the request, it should work like this.

The thing I don't catch is the answer and how to "send" it as answer to my httpRequest (that is waiting for the answer).

I have two cases :
Here, I would like to send the status of the answer to be able to tell to the app user wether the operation was successful. In which variable to I have to store the status and how to send it as answer to the httpRequest?
The second case is the case when my Post must return information to the app. I probably have to fetch it and to store it into an array in php. After, I am lost on how to send this array to the httpRequest.

Maybe I am completely wrong and I don't have to search that far...

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 fields at least: status and message. The most simple example in your case would be like

```php
<?php
//Header
header('Content-type: application/json');

try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=name', 'root', 'root');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $responseArray = array(
        'status' => 'false',
        'message' => 'MySQL connection error.'
    );
    die(json_encode($responseArray));
}

//Lecture du POST
$var1 = isset($_POST["var1"])? htmlspecialchars($_POST["var1"]): "";
$var2 = isset($_POST["var2"])? htmlspecialchars($_POST["var2"]): "";

//Insertion des données
$req = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (var1, var2) values (?,?)");
$execute = $req->execute(array($var1, $var2,))
if ($execute) {
    $responseArray = array(
        'status' => 'true',
        'message' => 'All data have been successfully stored.'
    );
} else {
    $responseArray = array(
        'status' => 'false',
        'message' => 'Error happened when storing data.'
    );
}

echo json_encode($responseArray);
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
How will the $responseArray variable be passed to my httpRequest? Does it happen automatically? If yes, could you give a little explanation, please? Is the name responseArray mandatory? I confess I am a little bit confused.
... or is it enough to have a json encoded variable?
Thanks again !